# ODI issues Error while processing statement: /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar does not exist

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have three virtual machines Oracle database, Hadoop server with Hive and Orcale Data Integrator. Each one has its own database. My goal is to connect all and doing a mapping from Hive database to Oracle database with Oracle Data Integrator.

I configure my Oracle and my Hive dataserver. the connection ist succefull then i create hive and oracle datamodels then a new mapping to load data from my hive table to mxy oracle table. at the logical tab i choose for Target Control Append. at the Physical Tab i choose for LKM: lkm hive to Oracle OLH-OSCH.GLOBAL and for IKM: ikm oracle insert.GLOBAL, but after pushing the play button I'm getting this Exception:

```
`ODI-1590: The execution of the script failed. 
Caused By: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Groovy: java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][Hive JDBC Driver][Hive]Error while processing statement: /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar does not exist
at org.codehaus.groovy.bsf.GroovyEngine.exec(GroovyEngine.java:114)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpScriptingInterpretor.
execInBSFEngine(SnpScriptingInterpretor.java:396)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpScriptingInterpretor.
exec(SnpScriptingInterpretor.java:247)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.interpreter.
SessionTaskScriptingInterpretor.scripting(SessionTaskScriptingInterpretor.java:190)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.scripting
(SessionTask.java:105)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.
ScriptingExecutor.execute(ScriptingExecutor.java:49)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.
ScriptingExecutor.execute(ScriptingExecutor.java:21) 
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.
handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:52)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.
processTask(SessionTask.java:206)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.
doExecuteTask(SessionTask.java:117)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.AbstractSessionTask.
execute(AbstractSessionTask.java:886)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.
SessionExecutor$SerialTrain.runTasks(SessionExecutor.java:2225)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor.
executeSession(SessionExecutor.java:610)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.
TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:718)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.
TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:611)
at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.
DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:203)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.
TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.doProcessStartAgentTask(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:800)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.
StartSessRequestProcessor.access$1400(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:74)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.
StartSessRequestProcessor$StartSessTask.doExecute(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:702)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.
AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:180)
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.
DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`
```

Comment: You should provide the code of the script you're trying to run or provide a description of what setup you did before pressing the play button. It's unlikely that someone will be able to help you debug with just the error that you got.

Comment: What is your HIVE_HOME set to? Can you confirm /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar is present?

Comment: HIVE_HOME is set and my hive-contrib.jar ist present

Comment: @JoeyHarwood i configure my Oracle and my Hive dataserver. the connection ist succefull then create a new mapping from my hive table to a oracle table.  at the logical tab i choose for Target Control Append. at the Physical Tab i choose for LKM: lkm hive to Oracle OLH-OSCH.GLOBAL and for IKM: ikm oracle insert.GLOBAL. let me kmow if you need more details                                                Best regards

Comment: @th12 I don't know oracle data integrator. I'm just trying to help you improve your question so those that do know it can help you. The best thing to do is to edit your question with those details so that potential answerers don't need to look in the comments for that information.